# How to check for Parse logged user while rendering server side?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, reactjs

- I use [Parse](https://www.parse.com) BaaS
- I have a [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) based web app created by [this generator](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) (which uses the latest ES syntax and [BabelJS](http://babeljs.io/))

I'm new to React, it took me a while to configure and get things working (on my machine and on my mind).

One of the greatest benefits of React is the semi-transparent server side rendering.

I wonder how (and if) I can check the user login status while rendering the page on the server side.

For now I'm not able to achieve it, and React is telling me that this is bad:

`Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server`